# Why does my ActionListener keep repeating?

Tags: java, actionlistener, repeat

I made a JButton and added an "AddActionListener" to it, but it keeps repeating the same action several times (2-6 times each time I press the button).

I'm sure I'll find it eventually, but can you see anything in this code that would show why it's repeating?

It shouldn't be possible for any of the methods it calls to make the action repeat. Also, I can call those methods from other places, and it's okay.

EDITED: Here is the whole code for the problem class:

Here is the whole code for the problem-class import

```
 public class Act
 {
private String title;
private Vector<Person> victims;
private Person victim;
private Person performer;
private Control control;
private Place oldPlace;
private JPanel oldPlacePanel;

public Cult theCult;
public Audience theAudience;
public Society theSociety;

private String description;

private JPanel actPanel;
private JTextArea actTextArea;
private JLabel actLabel;
//private JButton performButton;

private JComboBox victimsList;
private JLabel victimLabel;

private CultLeader leader;

private int charismaCost;
private Trait dominantTrait;
private int minimumPoints;

private boolean group;
private boolean individual;

private Trait streetSmart;
private Trait bookSmart;
private Trait cruel;
private Trait paranoid;
private Trait artistic;
private Trait powerHungry;
private Trait compassionate;
private Trait political;
private Trait sexual;
private Trait needy;
private Trait crazy;
private Trait adventurous;
private Trait practical;
private Trait sneaky;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public Act(String theTitle, CultLeader theLeader, Control theControl)
{
    leader = theLeader;
    title = theTitle;
    control = theControl;

    theAudience = control.theAudience;
    theCult = control.theCult;
    theSociety = control.theSociety;

    actTextArea = new JTextArea();
    actPanel = new JPanel();
    actLabel = new JLabel(title);

    victimsList = new JComboBox<String>();
    victimLabel = new JLabel();

    if (title == "Pamphlet")
    {
        makePamphlet();
    }
    else if (title == "Speech")
    {
        makeSpeech();

    }

    System.out.println("You created a " + title);
}

/**
 * This method turns THIS act (the currently-being-constructed Act object)
 * into a generic Pamphlet
 */
public void makePamphlet()
{
    charismaCost = 5;
    dominantTrait = new Trait("Paranoid");
    individual = true;
    group = false;

    description = "blah blah";
}   


/**
 * This method turns THIS act (the currently-being-constructed Act object)
 * into a generic Speech
 */
public void makeSpeech()
{
    charismaCost = 5;
    dominantTrait = new Trait("Crazy");
    individual = false;
    group = true;


    description = "blah blah";

}    

/**
 * Returns the title of this Act
 */
public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

/**
 * find out if this Act is meant for groups
 */
public boolean isGroup()
{
    return group;
}

/**
 * find out if this Act is meant for individuals
 */
public boolean isIndividual()
{
    return individual;
}

/**
 * This method will DISPLAY information about the Act in a JPanel in the bottom container in the Frame
 * It will show the description and the intended victims, then a Perform button.
 * 
 * There will be TWO displayAct methods... one which takes a single person as a victim
 * and a second, almost identical, which takes a Vector<Person>
 */
public JPanel displayAct(Person theVictim)
{
    victim = theVictim;

    actPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

    actPanel.removeAll();

    actTextArea.setText(description);
    actPanel.add(actLabel);
    actPanel.add(actTextArea);

    victimLabel.setText(theVictim.getName());

    actPanel.add(victimLabel);

    JButton performButton2 = new JButton("Perform Act");
    //setupSingleButton();
    //testButton();

    performButton2.setText("Give this " + title + " to " + victim.getName());
    performButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Action Started");
            //individualPerform(leader, victim);
        //control.personPanel.fillPanel(victim);
        //control.gui.changeMiddlePanel(victim.getPlace().getHerePanel());
        //System.out.println("ActionRepeated!");

        }
    });



    actPanel.add(performButton2);

    return actPanel;
}


private void testButton()
{
    performButton.setText("Give this " + title + " to " + victim.getName());
    performButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Action Started");
            //individualPerform(leader, victim);
        //control.personPanel.fillPanel(victim);
        //control.gui.changeMiddlePanel(victim.getPlace().getHerePanel());
        //System.out.println("ActionRepeated!");

        }
});
 }

private void setupSingleButton()
{
    performButton.removeAll();

    if (victim.getCurrentClub() == theSociety)
    {
    performButton.setText("Give this " + title + " to " + victim.getName());
    performButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r) {

            oldPlace = victim.getPlace();
            individualPerform(leader, victim);
        control.personPanel.fillPanel(victim);

        System.out.println("ActionRepeated!");
        control.gui.changeMiddlePanel(oldPlace.getHerePanel());
        }
    });
}
}


private void individualPerform(Person thePerformer, Person theVictim)
{
    performer = thePerformer;
    victim = theVictim;

        victim.increaseLoyalty(1);

}

private void groupPerform(Person thePerformer, Vector<Person> theVictims)
{
    performer = thePerformer;
    victims = theVictims;

    for (int i=0; i<theVictims.size(); i++)
    {
        if (theVictims.get(i).getCurrentClub() == thePerformer.theSociety)
        {
            theVictims.get(i).increaseLoyalty(1);
        }
    }
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call your `testButton` method it will call `addActionListener` again, which will add an additional listener. Make sure you're only adding the listener once.

If you need to call `testButton` repeatedly, then move the `addActionListener` call to a different method, or test if your listener has been added already by doing `if (performButton.getActionListeners().length == 0) { ... }`

Comment: That wasn't it. I tried putting the testButton call up in the constructor so it definitely only gets called once. This is weird. The first time I press the button it only does it once. But every subsequent time it loops a lot.

Comment: @MattPayne [MCVE needed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make sense of that, I think.

Comment: I think I solved it, and your comment led me to the solution so I'll call it solved. It had to do with the scope of the button... I declared the button in the constructor, and then I think it somehow added more ActionListeners. I'll try to post some more code, but my code is really swampy and full of interdependencies (it's my first application!).  I fixed it (for now) by putting the button inside the method that calls the JPanel, instead of inside the object whose information the JPanel displays.

Comment: I ADDED THE WHOLE CODE for the class. I have since FIXED it by moving the button's constructor to within the "displayAct" class, and moving the code for "setupButton" to within the same class. I still don't completely understand, but it works now. Somehow the single button, with a large scope, was getting multiple ActionListeners added onto it, but I didn't think I was calling that method multiple times.

Comment: @MattPayne There is a `performButton.addActionListener` call in `testButton`, and another one in `setupSingleButton`, so that's at least 2 listeners. Those methods are (or were) called from method `displayAct`. Presumably, you're calling `displayAct` several times, which would add another 2 listeners every time.

Comment: No, I had just one at first when I originally had the problem. I made a second one to experiment with so I didn't ruin the original. I would trim down that code, but both methods call the same problem so I left them for comparison. I had a class outside this class calling the "displayAct" method which might have added the actionListener more than once, but I haven't found why yet. When I change the scope so that the button only exists within displayAct, then everything is okay.